# Error in SCDF "a container name must be specified for pod xxxxxx-3o8kogmxmg, choose one of"

Tags: kubernetes, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow

We have run Spring Batch in GKE through SCDF and we use a sidecar container in this batch, so we have two container in pods. When I launch a task a try to get logs I get error in SCDF:

> "a container name must be specified for pod
> task-3o8kogmxmg, choose one of"

How to choose particular container in SCDF to get log from it?

Comment: if you only have one container inside your pods, 'kubectl logs $podname' shows the logs of the only one container. if there are more container, e.g. your sidecar 'kubectl logs $podname" does not know which container you want to have the logs for. 
you need to use "kubectl logs $podname $containername". Containernames can be found with "kubectl describe $podname"

Comment: Ok but how use it in SCDF? How pass to scdf that should chaosem batch container?

Comment: Ok, it is a bug https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer-kubernetes/issues/463